# Table of starting dates of each month in PBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to extract from Calendar table or how to generate from scratch a one column table containing only the first day of each month.

I can think of this:

```
SUMMARIZE(
'Calendar', 
'Calendar'[Date].[Year], 
'Calendar'[Date].[Month], 
"minDate", MIN('Calendar'[Date]) 
)
```

Of that I need only the column minDate. Could there be any simpler or more efficient way to generate such series of starting month dates?

[image]

The problem with my query is that it is 3 columns, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate from scratch:

```
first_day_of_month = 
DISTINCT (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2019, 1, 1 ), DATE ( 2019, 04, 01 ) ),
            [Date],
            "x", DATE ( YEAR ( [Date] ), MONTH ( [Date] ), 1 )
        ),
        "first_day_of_month", [x]
    )
)
```

A bit cleaner:

```
first_day_of_month =
GROUPBY (
    SUMMARIZE (
        CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2019; 1; 1 ); DATE ( 2019; 04; 01 ) );
        [Date];
        "first_day_of_month"; DATE ( YEAR ( [Date] ); MONTH ( [Date] ); 1 )
    );
    [first_day_of_month]
)
```

Comment: Hope you do not mind, I have restructured your code with https://www.daxformatter.com/ so that it is more readable for me. So generally your idea is to add [x] column to Calendar table which contains the first date of the month. And then your SUMMARIZE on Calendar on that column.

Comment: No worries, wasn't aware of that site but seems like a good tool. Yes that was my idea, but I gave it a bit more thought and realized it could be made cleaner, so I added another option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SELECTCOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectcolumns-function-dax) to return a table with only the column that you need.

```
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
    'Calendar', 
    'Calendar'[Date].[Year], 
    'Calendar'[Date].[Month], 
    "minDate", MIN('Calendar'[Date]) 
    ),
"minDate", [minDate])
```

Comment: You managed to reference column without referencing table as table[column]. It is very weird, nevertheless it works. Do you think your solution could be modified so that it references table of the column as well? Please see https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/table-and-column-references-using-dax-variables/ They say "Always use table names for column references".

Comment: Yeah, but they also say "We do not however think that is necessary in simple measures like the ones described in this article!" :) In this case, I don't think you should worry about that.