# Power BI how to add a new row based on condition after group

Tags: powerbi

I have a table like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16kBh.png)

I want to create a default value for each group(each month should have a default amount 0), I know we should do group function first, but I do not know want to do next, very appreciate who give me help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where you are going with your request. I understand it as: *Adding a row for the first day of each month with a default value of zero*.

This is not easy DAX. It's a bit complicated, so feel free to provide more info about your need, there may be another way more simple way.

The first step is to generate a table of the first day of each month. After a quick search, I've found a [way in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713626/table-of-starting-dates-of-each-month-in-pbi) and I was able to modify it a bit.

```
TABLE2 =
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            CALENDAR(
                DATE(2022, 01, 01),
                DATE(2022, 12, 01)
            ),
            "IsFDOM",
            IF(
                DAY([Date]) = 1,
                TRUE(),
                FALSE()
            )
        ),
        [IsFDOM] = TRUE()
    ),
    "DATA",
    [Date],
    "AMOUNT",
    0
)
```

What it does:

1. It generate a calendar between two dates I've arbitrary set : January 1st to Decembre 1st.
2. It adds a columns in this generated table `IsFDOM` (*Is First Day Of Month*) that return True is it is.
3. This table is then filtered to keep only the rows where `IsFDOM` is True.
4. It is wrapped in a `SELECTCOLUMNS` to keep and rename the columns you want and to match your existing table.

Next, you want to merge your existing table with this newly generated table. The DAX function to do it is [`UNION`](https://dax.guide/union/) and requires both table to have the same format - i.e same number of columns.

```
TABLENEW = 
UNION(
    TABLE1,
    FILTER(
        TABLE2,
        NOT TABLE2[DATA] IN VALUES(TABLE1[DATA])
    )
)
```

I've named you existing table `TABLE1` in this example.
The `FILTER` is used to not merge rows (dates) that already exist in `TABLE1`.

And, to make things even nicer. We can bypass the creation of `TABLE2` by embedding it in the table expression of `TABLENEW` :

```
TABLENEW = 
VAR MaxDate = 
MAX(TABLE1[DATA])
VAR TMP_Calendar =
FILTER(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER(
                ADDCOLUMNS(
                    CALENDAR(
                        DATE(2022, 01, 01),
                        DATE(2022, 12, 01)
                    ),
                    "IsFDOM",
                    IF(
                        DAY([Date]) = 1,
                        TRUE(),
                        FALSE()
                    )
                ),
                [IsFDOM] = TRUE()
            ),
            [Date],
            "default",
            0
        ),
        "DATA",
        [Date],
        "AMOUNT",
        [default]
    ),
    NOT [DATA] IN VALUES(TABLE1[DATA]) &&
    [DATA] <= MaxDate
)
RETURN
UNION(
    TABLE1,
    TMP_Calendar
)
```

The calendar formerly known as `TABLE2` is now created in a variable `TMP_Calendar`.
To make thing nicer, `MaxDate` calculate the max date of your existing table and only merge for existing date.